# Объединить синонимичные метки {"настройка", "настройки", "settings"}

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Количество вопросов по меткам:

- [настройка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0) - 101 вопрос;
- [настройки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b8) - 48 вопросов;
- [settings](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/settings) - 61 вопрос.

Предлагаю объединить эти метки, так как ими уже отмечены примерно соразмерные параллельные множества вопросов.

Опционально:
возможно их следует запретить использовать (из-за излишней абстрактности).

Comment: Где-то я уже видел такой вопрос. Хм.

Comment: Не дубликат, но про это уже как-то писали. В любом случае, надо объединить. Удалять нет смысла, опять наплодят. Хотя что такое настройки? Всмысле, это очень широкое понятие.

Answer (score 5):

Небольшая сводка спустя более 2 лет:

- `настройка` - 108 вопросов (+7 вопросов)
- `настройки` - 62 вопроса (+14 вопросов)
- `settings` - 71 вопрос (+10 вопросов)

Итого за 2 года задан всего 31 вопрос. Очевидно, все три метки не особо популярны (что само по себе НЕ является основанием к их удалению).

До сих пор ни у одной из этих меток нет ни описания, ни руководства по использованию (также не является основанием).

Я согласен с ответом αλεχολυτ, что "настройки" и "настройка" -- это разные метки.
Настройки -- это некие "правила", по которым работают приложения. Это **объект**, который может храниться и, как сказано в другом ответе, в каких-то файлах.
Настройка же это **процесс** изменения настроек, который можно провести, например, в
начале работы с приложением, чтобы сделать его более удобным для себя <strike>любимого</strike> и окружающих.

"Настройки" я бы перевел как "Settings", а "настройка" -- действительно "set-up". И вот эээто уже прямое основание к нижеизложенному:

Я считаю, что burnination (вроде так называется уничтожение метки) здесь неприменимо ни к одной из них и следует просто объединить метки `settings` и `настройки`, а `настройка` оставить без изменений.

> Этот ответ дан, чтобы поднять актуальность вопроса и не задавать новый дубликат.

Comment: Может более 4-х лет?)

Comment: 4 же *"более 2"*, так что все нормально ))

Comment: @EzioMercer А я откуда знаю, почему я написал два:) это же давно было, аж вчера, я уж и не помню)

Comment: @Kromster Ну ладно... я и не настаивал

Answer (score 2):

[настройки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b8) и [settings](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/settings) объединить имеет смысл, т.к. это действительно одно и то же, характерное для конфигурационных файлов всех сортов. Но вот [настройка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0)  — это по сути [set-up](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/set-up), то есть некая последовательность предварительных действий (процесс), которая тем не менее может затрагивать и файлы настроек, но не обязательно.